# How do I stain/paint Ikea birch Wardrobe pieces ebony?

Tags: wood, staining, sanding, polyurethane, particle-board

I don't like the Birch color much but I got a couple of those to use but would rather have the darker color. How do I go about making this change without ruining the wardrobe or the pieces please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my Particle-Board Cabinet re-staining project looking more professional please?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/46059/how-can-i-get-my-particle-board-cabinet-re-staining-project-looking-more-profess)

Comment: Not a duplicate because the cabinet in question is not laminate like this one is. As you see below, the suggestion is against staining it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling adventurous you could try spraying on a tinted top coat, that way you could achieve the ebony(ish) color and preserve the grain pattern. Its a tricky technique and it must be sprayed but it can be done.

There are a few variations but in general you add 10-20% dye stain to a finish like urethane or lacquer and spray on enough coats to get the color saturation you're after. Prep the surface as described by Steven and then apply an un-tinted clear sealer coat (my personal preference is Zinser's shellac based sealer). Sand with 280 and then add two coats of your tinted top coat, spraying in different directions (left to right then up to down). If it requires more coats, sand with 320-400 and continue on, sanding every few coats. If you have to let it sit for an extended period between coats (more than a day) be sure to sand to promote adhesion.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how it isn't real wood, rather just a thin laminate on top of MDF, I wouldn't bother trying to stain it and instead would just paint it.  Painting it shouldn't be any different than painting anything else really - lightly sand, prime and paint! Depending on the color and type of paint, you might need two or more coats.

If you haven't yet assembled the furniture, it would probably be easier to paint before assembling.

Comment: When I sand do I sand to remove the laminate entirely? And what paint do I use for this please?

Comment: I ask because I want to know if I should use latex or oil for this project.

Comment: Dont sand to remove the laminate. But you need to sand enough for the paint to stick..

Comment: Yes definitely don't remove the entire layer, just a light sand to help the new paint adhere better.  You should be able to use either latex or oil, I would probably opt for latex just because its easier to clean-up and smells less